# DISTINCT key word is not working in my query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In this query, DISTINCT key word is not working. display duplicate subjects from subject table.. can anybody tell me where I have made mistake?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  tutor_category_subject.subject_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects  
FROM       tutor_category_subject
INNER JOIN subject ON tutor_category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
WHERE tutor_category_subject.tutor_id = 3;
```

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203969/unexpected-sql-query-behavior-distinct/8203983#8203983

Comment: Your query has syntax errors. Please correct them.

Comment: Could you add some examples of the output where it is being duplicated?

Comment: sub_id =3, subject = Science and sub_id = 3, subject = Science

Comment: Are you sure that GROUP_CONCAT isn't introducing a space in one instance and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a group by statement:

```
SELECT tutor_category_subject.subject_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects  
FROM tutor_category_subject INNER JOIN
     subject
     ON tutor_category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
WHERE tutor_category_subject.tutor_id = 3
group by tutor_category_subject.subject_id
```